# How does a questions with -2/+2 votes count to the language badge?

Tags: support

If I answer for example a Java question with 2 downvotes and 2 upvotes, how does this counts for the Java tag? Do I have 0 or 2 upvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

*Score* is the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes (in other words, the number displayed between the vote buttons), so your example answer has a score of 0.